# Java 64 bit Error "UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified procedure could not be found"

Tags: java, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

My Java Application has JNI dll to be loaded at the beginning and we are using system.load() to load DLL with its full path. We have compiled the Java code with 64 bit JDK and dll we are trying to load is also compiled as 64 bit.

When i try to launch the Java application using java.exe at c:\windows\system32, it is successful in launching the application and when i try to launch the same Jar using the java.exe which is located in installed location i.e., %programfiles%\java\jre7\bin then it is failing with error "UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified procedure could not be found".

Can anybody explain the difference between java.exe available in c:\windows\system32 and at installed location?

Comment: Consider investigating where the JVM's look for DLL's.  This is most likely different.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two executables; They are one and the same.  Your problem is your DLL location relevant to where you start the Java Environment.

The property java.library.path needs to modified to point to where your DLL is located. You can alter this property by passing -Djava.library.path=

Comment: I am using System.load() and providing Full path of the DLL. Rest of dependencies of that DLL are present in %PATH% and i have verified it using tools like dependency walker. I did not used -Djava.library.path while Launching my Java application from command prompt.

Comment: @user3008675 The issue is that Java can't find your other dependencies.  Try adding windows\system32 to your java.library.path variable, or put your dll in windows\system32.

Answer (score 0):

Finally my problem is solved.

Actual problemis with libxml2. my applicat9on has dependency on libxml2. JRE 1.7.07 onards started using libxml2 and shipped into JRE location. hence there is conflict between different libxml2 DLLs. I have modified the application to load libxml2 dynamically and removed dependency.